# Decompose complete directed graph with n vertices into n edge-disjoint cycles with length n−1

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-cycles, hamiltonian-graphs

I want to know how to decompose a complete directed graph with $n$ nodes into $n$ edge-disjoint cycles with length $n-1$. I found this result was proved in [Bermond and Faber - Decomposition of the complete directed graph into
k-circuits](https://inria.hal.science/hal-02366539/file/11-BeFa76-Kn*%20en%20kcircuits.pdf) (Theorem 3). However, the proof is kind of difficult for me to understand, especially the construction seems ambiguous to me. Also, I am wondering whether this observation is true: there exists a decomposition such that all cycles (each expressed as a $1\times(n-1) $ vector and with appropriate shifting) can be written as a $n\times(n-1)$ matrix such that there is no repeated elements in each column. For example, when $n=4$, we consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&3&4\\1&4&3\\4&1&2\\3&2&1\end{bmatrix}$, in which each column does not have repeated elements, and each row represents a cycle (e.g., the first row is $2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 2$), it can be verified that all cycles are disjoint.

Comment: In case you don't already have it, here's $n=5$: $$\matrix{1&2&3&4\cr2&4&5&3\cr3&5&2&1\cr4&3&1&5\cr5&1&4&2\cr}$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. I have this. But cannot come up one with n=6. And I am wondering whether it is possible to prove or disprove it is always possible for general n.

Comment: I wonder whether an even stronger result might be true, that one can always arrange for the matrix, leaving out the bottom row, to be symmetric.

Comment: I found none for $n=6$ by computer exhaustive search, and some for $n=3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11$. Furthermore, all solutions show @GerryMyerson 's symmetry for $n=3,4,5,7$. There always are some showing the symmetry for $n=8,9,10,11$. And some not showing it for $n=8,9$ (I haven't looked for them yet for $n=10$ or $11$).

Answer (score 2):

The problem of decomposing the complete directed graph on $n$ vertices into directed cycles of length $m$ was completely settled in Alspach, Gavlas, Sajna, and Verrall, Cycle decompositions IV: complete directed graphs and fixed length directed cycles, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, 103 (2003) 165-208, available at https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81154598.pdf  The main result is

1.1. Theorem. For positive integers $m$ and $n$, with $2\le m\le n$, the digraph $K=K_n^*$ can be decomposed into directed cycles of length $m$ if and only if $m$ divides the number of arcs in $K$ and $(m,n)\ne(4,4),(6,3),(6,6)$.

In the special case that concerns us here, the case $m=n-1$, we have,

Lemma 5.7. For each odd integer $m\ge5$, the complete directed graph $K_{m+1}^*$ can be decomposed into directed $m$-cycles.

[Note that we already have the case $m=3$, so this settles in the affirmative the case $m$ odd.]

While the paper is long and difficult, the proof of Lemma 5.7 is less than half a page, and doesn't look too bad (although it does rely on notation defined on previous pages). I encourage you to try to work through it in the case $m=5$, $n=6$.

The paper says the case $m$ odd, $n$ even is the hardest case, so maybe the case where $m=n-1$ is even can also be handled without too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. The construction in this paper is similar to the one I referred in the question. Unfortunately, this construction does not satisfy the property described (i.e., there is no repeated element in each column)

Comment: DOI for AGSV: https://doi.org/10.1016/S0097-3165(03)00098-0.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the highly symmetric pattern you and @GerryMyerson have observed, consider the $n$-cycle permutation $\sigma$  of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ defined by
$$\begin{array}{c}
1 \quad\to\quad 2\!\to\!4\!\to\!6\to\!\cdots\!\to (4m) \quad\to\quad (4m\!-\!1)\\
(4m\!-\!1\!)\to\!(4m\!-\!3)\!\to\!\cdots\!\to\!(2m\!+\!1) \;\to\; (4m\!+\!1) \;\to\; (2m\!-\!1)\!\to\!(2m\!-\!3)\!\to\!\cdots\!\to\!1
\end{array}$$
when $n=4m+1$, and
$$\begin{array}{c}
1 \quad\to\quad 2\!\to\!4\!\to\!6\to\!\cdots\!\to (4m+2) \quad\to\quad (4m\!+\!1)\\
(4m\!+\!1\!)\!\to\!(4m\!-\!1)\!\to\!\cdots\!\to\!(2m\!+\!3) \;\to\; (4m\!+\!3) \;\to\; (2m\!+\!1)\!\to\!(2m\!-\!1)\!\to\!\cdots\!\to\!1
\end{array}$$
when $n=4m+3$.

For small $n$ it is :

$$\begin{array}{rrlcrrr}
4\times 0+3,\quad&1 \;\to& 2 &\to&&3\;\to&\!1\\
4\times 1+1,\quad&1 \;\to& 2\!\to\! 4 &\to&3 \;\to&5\;\to&\! 1\\
4\times 1+3,\quad&1 \;\to& 2\!\to\! 4\!\to\! 6 &\to&5 \;\to&7\;\to&\! 3\!\to\! 1\\
4\times 2+1,\quad&1 \;\to& 2\!\to\! 4\!\to\! 6\!\to\! 8 &\to&7\!\to\! 5 \;\to&9\;\to&\! 3\!\to\! 1\\
4\times 2+3,\quad&1 \;\to& 2\!\to\! 4\!\to\! 6\!\to\! 8\!\to\! 10 &\to&9\!\to\! 7 \;\to&\!\!\!11\;\to&\!\!5\!\to\! 3\!\to\! 1\\
4\times 3+1,\quad&1 \;\to& 2\!\to\! 4\!\to\! 6\!\to\! 8\!\to\! 10\!\to\! 12&\to&11\to9\!\to\! 7 \;\to&\!\!\!13\;\to&\!\!5\!\to\! 3\!\to\! 1
\end{array}$$

In two-line notation it is :

$$n = 3 = 4\times 0+3,\qquad\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
2&3&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$n = 5 = 4\times 1+1,\qquad\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5\\
2&4&5&3&1
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$n = 7 = 4\times 1+3,\qquad\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
2&4&1&6&7&5&3
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$n = 9 = 4\times 2+1,\qquad\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
2&4&1&6&9&8&5&7&3
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$n = 11 = 4\times 2+3,\qquad\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
2&4&1&6&3&8&11&10&7&9&5
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$n = 13 = 4\times 3+1,\qquad\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
2&4&1&6&3&8&13&10&7&12&9&11&5
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now write the $n$ iterations $\text{Id}, \sigma, \sigma^2, \dots, \sigma^{n-1}$ of $\sigma$ in one-line notation, stack them as $n$ rows, sort the rows in lexical order, and ignore the last column -- I've greyed it out below.
The $n\times n$ matrix then starts with the two-line notation above :

$n = 3 = 4\times 0+3,$
$$\begin{array}{r}
\color{grey}{\sigma^0}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^1}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^2}
\end{array}\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&\color{grey}{3}\\
2&3&\color{grey}{1}\\
3&1&\color{grey}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$n = 5 = 4\times 1+1,$
$$\begin{array}{r}
\color{grey}{\sigma^0}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^1}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^3}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^2}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^4}
\end{array}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&\color{grey}{5}\\
2&4&5&3&\color{grey}{1}\\
3&5&2&1&\color{grey}{4}\\
4&3&1&5&\color{grey}{2}\\
5&1&4&2&\color{grey}{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$n = 7 = 4\times 1+3,$
$$\begin{array}{r}
\color{grey}{\sigma^0}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^1}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^6}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^2}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^4}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^3}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^5}
\end{array}\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&\color{grey}{7}\\
2&4&1&6&7&5&\color{grey}{3}\\
3&1&7&2&6&4&\color{grey}{5}\\
4&6&2&5&3&7&\color{grey}{1}\\
5&7&6&3&2&1&\color{grey}{4}\\
6&5&4&7&1&3&\color{grey}{2}\\
7&3&5&1&4&2&\color{grey}{6}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$n = 9 = 4\times 2+1,$
$$\begin{array}{r}
\color{grey}{\sigma^0}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^1}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^8}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^2}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^6}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^3}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^5}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^4}\\
\color{grey}{\sigma^7}
\end{array}\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&\color{grey}{9}\\
2&4&1&6&9&8&5&7&\color{grey}{3}\\
3&1&9&2&7&4&8&6&\color{grey}{5}\\
4&6&2&8&3&7&9&5&\color{grey}{1}\\
5&9&7&3&6&1&4&2&\color{grey}{8}\\
6&8&4&7&1&5&3&9&\color{grey}{2}\\
7&5&8&9&4&3&2&1&\color{grey}{6}\\
8&7&6&5&2&9&1&3&\color{grey}{4}\\
9&3&5&1&8&2&6&4&\color{grey}{7}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$n = 11 = 4\times 2+3,$
$$\color{grey}{\begin{array}{r}
\sigma^0\\
\sigma^1\\
\sigma^{10}\\
\sigma^2\\
\sigma^9\\
\sigma^3\\
\sigma^7\\
\sigma^4\\
\sigma^6\\
\sigma^5\\
\sigma^8
\end{array}}\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&\color{grey}{11}\\
2&4&1&6&3&8&11&10&7&9&\color{grey}{5}\\
3&1&5&2&11&4&9&6&10&8&\color{grey}{7}\\
4&6&2&8&1&10&5&9&11&7&\color{grey}{3}\\
5&3&11&1&7&2&10&4&8&6&\color{grey}{9}\\
6&8&4&10&2&9&3&7&5&11&\color{grey}{1}\\
7&11&9&5&10&3&6&1&4&2&\color{grey}{8}\\
8&10&6&9&4&7&1&11&3&5&\color{grey}{2}\\
9&7&10&11&8&5&4&3&2&1&\color{grey}{6}\\
10&9&8&7&6&11&2&5&1&3&\color{grey}{4}\\
11&5&7&3&9&1&8&2&6&4&\color{grey}{10}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$n = 13 = 4\times 3+1,$
$$\color{grey}{\begin{array}{r}
\sigma^0\\
\sigma^1\\
\sigma^{12}\\
\sigma^2\\
\sigma^{11}\\
\sigma^3\\
\sigma^9\\
\sigma^4\\
\sigma^8\\
\sigma^5\\
\sigma^7\\
\sigma^6\\
\sigma^{10}
\end{array}}\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&\color{grey}{13}\\
2&4&1&6&3&8&13&10&7&12&9&11&\color{grey}{5}\\
3&1&5&2&13&4&9&6&11&8&12&10&\color{grey}{7}\\
4&6&2&8&1&10&5&12&13&11&7&9&\color{grey}{3}\\
5&3&13&1&7&2&11&4&12&6&10&8&\color{grey}{9}\\
6&8&4&10&2&12&3&11&5&9&13&7&\color{grey}{1}\\
7&13&9&5&11&3&10&1&8&2&6&4&\color{grey}{12}\\
8&10&6&12&4&11&1&9&3&7&5&13&\color{grey}{2}\\
9&7&11&13&12&5&8&3&6&1&4&2&\color{grey}{10}\\
10&12&8&11&6&9&2&7&1&13&3&5&\color{grey}{4}\\
11&9&12&7&10&13&6&5&4&3&2&1&\color{grey}{8}\\
12&11&10&9&8&7&4&13&2&5&1&3&\color{grey}{6}\\
13&5&7&3&9&1&12&2&10&4&8&6&\color{grey}{11}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't know why this works out so symmetyrically and haven't figured it out for $n$ even.